# How to cite bibliography in XSL transformation of XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

**Problem**: I want to cite bibliography that is in XML file, which is transformed to an HTML page using XSL. The bibliography is defined as follows:

```
<bibliography>
        <bibitem bibid="b1">
            <title>Genome-enabled development of DNA markers of ecology, evolution and conservation. Molecular Ecology 19</title>
            <authors>
                <author>Thomson, R. C.</author>
                <author>Wang, I. J.</author>
                <author>Johnson, J. R.</author>
            </authors>
            <date>2010</date>
            <other>2184-2195</other>
        </bibitem>
        <bibitem bibid="b2">
        ...
```

My question is, how can I represent the reference, by a number, to a bibitem, in the HTML page? For example:

```
"...and genes are molecular units of heredity that code a protein. [1] ...
```

This means I'm citing the bibitem with the attribute "b1". Plus, reference [2] means to bibitem="b2" and so on. But how can I make this "map-like" association using XSL transformation?

Comment: What is the rule for the numbering? Is the bibliography an external document of the XML you are processing?

Comment: Yes, the bibliography is from a PDF thesis, and the example above is just a small piece of the xml thesis. What I want to do is to transform the content of the XML thesis (using XSL) to HTML, in which I want to make the references to bibliography appear in the text, just like I've written

Comment: I've tried to use xsl:key to do that, but that only replaces the reference for information belonging to the referenced objet, in this case, the bibliography element.

Comment: Does the XML input referencing a bititem have any XML markup in form of an attribute or element? Or does it just have the plain text `[1]` and XSLT would need to parse the plain text for any square brackets with numbers in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a tag like `<cite bibref="b1" />` to insert the reference in the thesis text, you can do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="cite">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('citebib', @bibid)" mode="cite"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bibitem" mode="cite">
  <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
  <xsl:number />
  <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

In this case, the number is simply retrieved from the index position of the `<bibitem>` element in its `<bibliography>` parent element.

You can also use the apply-templates on the element retrieved from the key you declared. You should post also relevant elements from your XSL.

Comment: <xsl:key name="citebib" match="//bibitem" use="@bibid"/> <xsl:template match="cite">
        
        [<xsl:value-of select="key('citebib',@bibid)/title"/>]
        
</xsl:template>

Comment: I've used the same attribute on both cite and bibitem

Comment: So you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('citebib', @bibid)" mode="cite"/>`

Comment: Like this? `
<xsl:key name="citebib" match="//bibitem" use="@bibid"/>

<xsl:template match="cite">
        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('citebib', @bibid)" mode="cite"/>
        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bibitem" mode="cite">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: What do mean? Does the template always return "[1]"?

Comment: OK, using `<xsl:number />` is better. I have corrected the answer.